# LINQ / EF - Only return items based on a list of ID's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of type int, which contains ID's. For example it may contain 1,2,5,8,16 or 2,3,6,9,10,12 etc..

I then want to return all of my "Enquiries" based on the ID's stored in my list (called vehicles) and return them as a list, something like:

```
var enquiries = context.Enquiries.Where(x => x.EnquiryID == vehicles.Any()).ToList();
```

But obviously this doesn't work, is there something similar I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to use Contains.  Contains (in Linq2SQL or EF) will be transformed into a WHERE/IN clause.

```
 enquiries = context.Enquiries
                    .Where( x => vehicles.Contains( x.EnquiryID ) )
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! I will accept as answer when I'm allowed too